# Scheduling Outlook meeting in Vue.js application without ActiveX

Tags: javascript, outlook, activex

Is there a way to schedule a meeting in Outlook from a web application without using ActiveX? Since Chrome does not support ActiveX, I need a work around. I am able to generate emails just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with Exchange profile you may consider using REST API or Exchnage Web Services, see [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.